# How to create if/else statement for certain conditions

Tags: flutter

So I was asked to create this condition on the signup page of my program.

Field validation should check the length of a cell number I.g +639/09- if user inputs +639 it should validate how many numbers was inputed

for +639 the max character should be 13 characters max,

for numbers starting in 09, max characters should be "11".

This is my original code, and I have no idea on how to make an else if statement for the said problem.

```
>   Widget signupPage() {
>     bool isAllowedToGoNext = isAgree == true &&
>         firstname.text.length > 0 &&
>         lastname.text.length > 0 &&
>         contactNo.text.length == 11 &&
>         isEmailInvalid == false &&
>         isEmailTaken == false &&
>         isPasswordNotMatch == false;
```

And this is the code for the contact number

```
    Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 20.0,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    '* ',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Mobile No.",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: CompanyColors.grey[50],
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                  ),
                ),
                isContactNumberTaken == true
                    ? Text(
                        " * Contact number has already taken",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.redAccent,
                          fontSize: 13.0,
                        ),
                      )
                    : Text(''),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(
                      color: isContactNumberTaken == true
                          ? Colors.redAccent
                          : CompanyColors.appleGreen,
                      width: isContactNumberTaken == true ? 2 : 0.5,
                      style: BorderStyle.solid),
                ),
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 10.0),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (String value) async {
                        isUserAllowedToImageVerification();
  },
                      controller: contactNo,
                      obscureText: false,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                      maxLength: 11,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        counterText: '',
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description

```dart
if (text.startsWith('+639')) {
    if (text.length > 13) {
      // ...
    }
} else if (text.startsWith('09')) {
    if (text.length > 11) {
      // ...
    }
} else {
    // neither
}
```

Comment: Yes, since there probably no `else` after `if (text.length > 13) {...}` this is a more concise way.

Comment: Thank you for the answers kind gentlemen. I'm new to flutter so I don't really know much. Can you please tell me in what part of my existing code  should I place the code  that you gave me. I really appreciate it

Comment: Okay, I just figure out what you mean. Replace `contactNo.text.length == 11` with ((text.startsWith('+639') && text.length > 13)||text.startsWith('09') && text.length > 11). Btw, maybe you will remove `maxLength: 11` in your code

Comment: Thank you so much for the help sir. Much appreciated

Comment: One last question sir, sorry for the trouble.

How can I achieve this conditions ?

ex.
092345595959
if 09 = true
if 11 digits = true

if +63 = false
if  13 digits = false.

Comment: I don't really undertand your question. Maybe you can tell me your initial problem

Comment: Some suggestions. It appears that your problem is nothing about flutter, but basic programming skills. Maybe you need more programming practice. [Leetcode](http://leetcode.com) is a good place to have a practice. If you have problems with dart, see [https://dart.dev/guides](https://dart.dev/guides).